Duplicate attribute error after setting up Xunit
After I have followed these instructions to set up Xunit, I get the following error when running dotnet test.
/path/to/project/Release/net8.0/osx-x64/.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
I have run dotnet clean and tried removing the obj folder, but the error persists.
Here is my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64;osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>      
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <Version>0.0.1</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


And here is my Proj.Tests.csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="Xunit" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Proj.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this so that I can start creating some unit tests?
